# Under the equal integral, when the integrand become equal or what is the relationship between the integrand?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I want to find the relation between integrand for certain cases:

1. Suppose
   \begin{align}
   \int_x F(x) = \int_{x} G(x)
   \end{align}
   Then when we can think $F(x) = G(x)$?  Obviously, when $F(x) = G(x)$, $\int_{x} F(x) = \int_{x} G(x)$. I want to know the converse, or the relation between $F(x)$ and $G(x)$.

--- Of course, one can think of the boundary term so that $F(x) = G(x) + \int_{x} D(x)$ so that $\int_{x} D(x) =0$, and neglecting boundary terms we might get $F(x) = G(x)$ up to the boundary.

2. Now consider a multi-variable case
   \begin{align}
   \int_{x,y} F_{x,y} = \int_{x,y} G_{x,y}
   \end{align}
   (Here I assume the function $F(x,y), G(x,y)$ satisfies the condtion in Fubini's theorem)

Then when we can think $F_{x,y} = G_{x,y}$?  Here the integration of $x,y$ seems important and we might think the symmetric or anti-symmetric of $F_{x,y}$ and $G_{x,y}$. i.e., $F_{x,y} = F_{y,x}$, $F_{x,y} = - F_{y,x}$ etc.

For example, we can set $F_{x,y}$ be symmetric so $F_{x,y} = \frac{1}{2} (G_{x,y} + G_{y,x})$, then the anti-symmetric parts of $G_{x,y}$ can be imposed to meet $\int_{x,y} F_{x,y} = \int_{x,y} G_{x,y}$

For the second case, let me ignore the boundary terms. [I am not sure of the boundary term at this moment]

Comment: Assuming you're talking about definite integrals, so that both expressions are numbers: I wouldn't expect any relationship between $F(x)$ and $G(x)$ other than the one given. Integration is a limit of sums, so we can ask ourselves the analogous question for sums: if $a_1+\cdots+a_9 = b_1+\cdots+b_9$, should expect $a_1=b_1$ and $a_2=b_2$ and ... and $a_9=b_9$?

Comment: For indefinite integrals, taking the derivative of both sides gives $F = G$. Your comments about $D$ are nonsensical, as you are confusing $F - G$ with $\int_x F - \int_x G$. For the multivariable case, you would first have to define what you even mean by $\int_{x,y} F(x,y)$ as an indefinite integral.